# Any good software for fermionic operator algebra manipulation?

Tags: programming, linear-algebra

Suppose I have some ground state $a^\dagger_{k_1,\sigma_1}a^\dagger_{k_2,\sigma_2}a^\dagger_{k_3,\sigma_3}|\emptyset\rangle$ where $|\emptyset\rangle$ is the vacuum, $k_i$ is some quantum number and $\sigma_i$ are the spins.

Now suppose I want to calculate, for example something like this

$$\langle A|\sum_{\sigma\sigma'\lambda\lambda'}\sum_{kk'p'p'qq' rr'}a^\dagger_{p\lambda}a^\dagger_{p'\lambda'}a_{q'\lambda'}a_{q'\lambda}a^\dagger_{q\sigma}a^\dagger_{q'\sigma'}a_{k'\sigma'}a_{k\sigma}|A\rangle$$
Clearly there are many ways to simplify this equation.

What would be the best software (Mathematica or Python based) to ALGEBRAICALLY do so? If not how could I code something to simplify such an expression.

Comment: This should be doable in Mathematica but I don't have access to it anymore. I use GAP (open source) with the GBPNP package https://www.gap-system.org/Packages/gbnp.html and it works well. Caveats : GAP only works with rational and algebraic numbers (no floating point)...that might be an advantage rather than a disadvantage